# Setting dictionarys equal in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to programming so hopefully the answer will be easy. I was trying to set a dictionary equal to another dictionary, but whenever the second dictionary changed values, so did the first one. (without me telling it to.) For example

```
dictA = {'a':1}
dictB = {}
for x in range (1,5):
    dictB = dictA
    print "dictB is ",
    print dictB
    dictA['a'] += 1
    print "dictA is ",
    print dictA
    print "and dictB is ",
    print dictB
```

Returns:

```
dictB is  {'a': 1}
dictA is  {'a': 2}
and dictB is  {'a': 2}
dictB is  {'a': 2}
dictA is  {'a': 3}
and dictB is  {'a': 3}
dictB is  {'a': 3}
dictA is  {'a': 4}
and dictB is  {'a': 4}
dictB is  {'a': 4}
dictA is  {'a': 5}
and dictB is  {'a': 5}
```

Is there a way to maintain the value of dictB until the end of the loop?
Thanks

Comment: I do not agree with closing of this question based on this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251938/should-i-flag-a-question-as-duplicate-if-it-has-received-better-answers, I think the question and the answer are better presented here than in the original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are simply creating a reference to the same object. Try using [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) or `dict.copy()` instead:

```
from copy import deepcopy

dictB = deepcopy(dictA)
```

Or:

```
dictB = dictA.copy()
```

#### Demo

```
a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

b = a

>>> print id(a)
2118820
>>> print id(b)     #same id
2118820

from copy import deepcopy

b = deepcopy(a)

print id(a)
2118820
print id(b)
1787364     #different id
```

#### Demo 2

```
a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

print id(a)

b = a.copy()

print id(b)

a['a'] = 5

print a,b
```

One thing to keep in mind about `copy()` is that:

> `dict.copy()` creates a new dict with a different id, but just uses
>   the same keys and values whereas `deepcopy` also copies the values. -@tdelaney

Comment: could you add some comments on why `dictB = dictA.copy()` does not work?

Comment: `dict.copy()` will make a copy, and not "will give you a pointer to the same object" as you said. `.copy()` works for simple dicts without references in it.

Comment: dict.copy creates a new dict with a different id, but just uses the same keys and values. deepcopy also copies the values. Deepcopy is useful when you have mutable types like lists and other dicts. In the example, a simple copy is all you need.

Comment: As it stands the answer is misleading; I would be happy to undo my -1 once the copy issue is explained.

Comment: @Akavall, I hope my edit is sufficient enough

Comment: @sshashank124, looks good to me.